# Trying to find information about intraspecific allelic expression divergence in recombinant individuals due to changes in the cis regulatory regions

Tags: genetics, evolution, allele, recombination

I am trying to find any research articles or resources that focus on differences in expression levels at the allelic level due to changes in cis regulatory regions in recombinant individuals. For example, when recombination occurs near a gene it can cause the promoter regions from the two parental alleles to swap places, which can then affect binding affinity so that one parental allele is preferred over the other and is thus over-expressed. I've seen work that deals with various hybrid crosses that show differences in parental allele expression. But I am curious if there is anything that shows how expression patterns can flip in a recombinant individual when compared to the expression patterns in the hybrid of the parental haplotypes. Further, I'm curious if this happens in a tissue specific manner, i.e. can the same gene have one allele that is overexpressed in Tissue 1 (the paternal allele can be preferred in this tissue), and then the same gene has the opposite expression where the maternal allele is overexpressed in Tissue 2. This is in a case where trans-acting factors are controlled for to ensure that differential expression is due to changes in the cis-regulatory regions. Hopefully my question is clear, if it isn't I can clarify. Thanks for any help!